# Displaying popup messages/modals with Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-web-addins

I am currently developing an Outlook Add-In that receives a notification whenever a change in the user's calendar is recorded. The thing is that, there are some occasions where we would change an event's date from the backend by calling `PATCH /events/eventId`.

It would be very nice if there was any way to notify the user immediately, other than sending an email. Something like a popup modal with a warning message would work very well.

Comment: It would be great to get this as an actual answer to the question and not a comment on the question. So that this could be marked as an answer to their response.

Comment: Promoted previous comment to an answer. Thanks @JeremyThakeMSFT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the feature you requested is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.